# Activity launched with deeplink got finished when choosing app to open

Tags: android

I want to implement deeplink where if a logged in user opens a link, the app launches an activity, but for non-logged in user, the app launches login activity (and also passing the deeplink scheme extra to that activity) then after logging in, the app redo the deeplink and finishes the login activity.

But the problem is, when I finished logging in, the login activity got finished before I was done with the "choose app to open" prompt. Resulting the activity got redirected to MainActivity after opening the previously intended deeplink activity for a few second.

```
private fun redirectAfterLoggedIn() {
        if (isOpenFromDeeplink()) {
            openDeeplinkScheme()
        } else {
            openUserActivity()
        }
    }

private fun openDeeplinkScheme() {
        viewModel.deeplinkScheme?.let { scheme ->
            startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(scheme)))
            finish()
        }
    }
```

deeplinkScheme variable is a deeplink scheme string, retrieved from previous activity

Answer (score 0):

move `finish()` to `onActivityResult` in the activity.

```
private fun openDeeplinkScheme() {
    viewModel.deeplinkScheme?.let { scheme ->
      startActivityForResult(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(scheme)), 100);  
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == 100) {
      // do some optional data manipulation
      finish()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks good suggestion, but you mean requestCode == 100 right? cause I wont return any result from the other Activity